# program terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, macos

I am trying to go through an xml file and display the contents

```
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
    NSString *xmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xml" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSString *xml = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSXMLDocument *xmlDocument = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:xml options:0 error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSXMLElement *node in [xmlDocument.rootElement nodesForXPath:@"//app" error:nil])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSMutableArray *photos = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (NSXMLElement *subNode in node.children)
        {
            if ([subNode.name isEqualToString:@"address"])
                [photos addObject:subNode.stringValue];
            else
                [dict setObject:subNode.stringValue forKey:subNode.name];
        }

        [dict setObject:photos forKey:@"address"];
        [array addObject:dict];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", array);
    return 0;
```

}

But I'm getting an error in this line

```
NSXMLDocument *xmlDocument = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:xml options:0 error:nil];
```

The error says
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

please help

Comment: Show the whole error message that you get in console. It should give useful hints about your issue. Are you sure `xml` is not nil? If that's the case, what about using the `error` parameters you have?

Answer (score 0):

check that *xml* NSString is not nil

Comment: @BharathSuresh By doing as I said: instead of writing `error:nil`, what about using that parameter?

Answer (score 0):

**Read from local path**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xml.xml"];
```

**Then use from local path**

```
NSURL *xmlFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appFile];
 NSXMLParser *addressParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlFile];
```

**NOTE**: NSXMLDocument is an OS X only class

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You cant use it in iOS.

On iOS you can use **NSXMLParser**.

Comment: I'm not trying this for iOS. I want it to work for OS X only.